# How to insert a row using VBA when a value is entered in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone can help with this. I'm a BIG novice when it comes to VBA and was hoping that someone could help me out.

I would like to have a Macro created that inserts a row directly underneath the current row when a value is entered in the "Next to Action" Column and would re-enter (copy) the information from the first 2 cells (Name and Date).

Here is my example. So by adding the name of Bobby in line 1 under "Next to Action" it would insert a row between John and Peter and re-enter John's name and Date.

| Name | Date | Action By | Next to Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 25/04/2023 | Tim | Bobby |
| Peter | 17/05/2023 | Richard | Mark |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

The information that I found doesn't help and could only find information on inserting rows with values already entered.

Comment: You'll need the `Worksheet.Change` event for this.

Answer (score 1):

Add change event code into worksheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column = 4 And Len(Trim(.Value)) > 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Rows(.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Cells(.Row + 1, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Cells(.Row, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What would I change in order to include Column C in the information copied to the next cell?

Comment: It's easy. `Cells(.Row + 1, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Cells(.Row, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value` Directly set cells value is more efficient than copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code based on your need

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' This is an event handler that triggers whenever there's a change on the worksheet.
    ' It monitors changes in the specified range (the "Next to Action" column).
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newRow As Range
    
    ' Declare variables to hold range objects.
    
    Set rng = Me.Range("D:D")
    ' Define the range where the "Next to Action" column is located.
    ' "Me" refers to the worksheet containing this code.
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' Check if the changed cell is within the defined range.
        
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            ' Check if the changed cell has a value.
            
            Dim rowNum As Long
            rowNum = Target.Row
            ' Get the row number of the changed cell.
            
            Set newRow = Me.Rows(rowNum + 1)
            newRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            ' Create a new row underneath the changed cell's row.
            ' xlShiftDown specifies that existing rows should be shifted downward.
            
            Me.Cells(rowNum, 1).Copy Destination:=newRow.Cells(1, 1)
            Me.Cells(rowNum, 2).Copy Destination:=newRow.Cells(1, 2)
            ' Copy the values from the first two cells of the original row to the new row.
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the sheet's module to invoke change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
If Target.value <> "" And Not Intersect(Target, Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
With Target
Rows(.Row + 1).Insert xlDown
.Offset(1, -3) = .Offset(0, -3)
.Offset(1, -2) = .Offset(0, -2)
End With
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Improved on comment

Comment: Clearing a cell in column D triggers the Change event to insert a new row.